# How can I use hash sets in java to determine if a string contains valid characters?

Tags: java, hashset

I'm writing a lexical analyzer and have never used hash sets. I want to take a string and make sure it's legal. I think I understand how to build the hash set with valid characters but I'm not sure how to compare the string with teh hash set to ensure it contains valid characters. I can't find an example anywhere. Can someone point me to code that would do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Anything specific you are having trouble with?

Answer (score 3):

HashSet has the function contains() for this, since it implements the Collection interface.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot compare an entire string to a `HashSet<Character>`, but you can do it one character at a time:

```
HashSet<Character> valid = new HashSet<Character>();
valid.add('a');
valid.add('d');
valid.add('f');
boolean allOk = true;
for (char c : "fad".toCharArray()) {
    if (!valid.contains(c)) {
        allOk = false;
        break;
    }
}
System.out.println(allOk);
```

However, this is not the most efficient way of doing it. A better approach would be to construct a regex with the characters that you need, and call `match()` on the string:

```
// Let's say x, y, and z are the valid characters
String regex = "[xyz]*";
if (myString.matches(regex)) {
    System.out.println("All characters in the string are in 'x', 'y', and 'z'");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are probably over-thinking this problem.  (For instance, spending too much time thinking how to make the lexer "efficient" ...)

The conventional ways to test for valid / invalid characters in a lexer are:

- use a big switch statement, or
- perform a sequence of "character class" tests; e.g. using the result of `Character.getType(char)`

Or better still, use a lexer generator.

---

Using a HashSet is neither more efficient or more readable than a `switch`.  And the "character class" approach *could* be a lot more readable than both ... depending on your validation rules.